# Ionic Native Contacts Problem display each number

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I hope you are well.

I have a problem with Ionic Contacts.

I am getting all the contacts with my code right now but I need to extract each contact with each number for exemple if John Doe has 3 phone number I would like to display in front-end John Doe with first phone number , John Doe with second phone number and John Doe with 3rd number.

Code :

```
loadContacts() {
    let options = {
      filter: "",
      multiple: true,
      hasPhoneNumber: true,
    };
    this.contacts.find(["*"], options).then((contacts: Contact[]) => {
      this.myContacts = contacts;
      console.log("Contacts:", contacts);
    });
  }
```

```
 <ion-list
          lines="none"
          *ngFor="let c of myContacts"
          class="ion-no-padding"
        >
          <ion-item class="ion-no-padding" (ionChange)="onCheckbox($event)">
            <h5>{{c.name.givenName}} {{c.name.familyName}}</h5>
         </ion-item>
          <p *ngFor="let p of c.phoneNumbers" class="phone">
            {{p.value}} </p
</ion-list>
```

```
The array of objects is looking like this : 

 testContact = {
    _objectInstance: {
      id: 3,
      rawId: null,
      displayName: null,
      name: {
        givenName: "John",
        honorificSuffix: "",
        formatted: "John Appleseed",
        middleName: "",
        familyName: "Appleseed",
        honorificPrefix: "",
      },
      nickname: "",
      phoneNumbers: [
        { value: "888-555-5512", pref: false, id: 0, type: "mobile" },
        { value: "888-555-1212", pref: false, id: 1, type: "home" },
      ],
      emails: [
        { value: "John-Appleseed@mac.com", pref: false, id: 0, type: "work" },
      ],
      addresses: [
        {
          pref: "false",
          locality: "Atlanta",
          region: "GA",
          id: 0,
          postalCode: "30303",
          country: "USA",
          type: "work",
          streetAddress: "3494 Kuhl Avenue",
        },
        {
          pref: "false",
          locality: "Atlanta",
          region: "GA",
          id: 1,
          postalCode: "30303",
          country: "USA",
          type: "home",
          streetAddress: "1234 Laurel Street",
        },
      ],
      ims: null,
      organizations: [
        { pref: "false", title: "", name: "", department: "", type: null },
      ],
      birthday: "1980-06-22T12:00:00.000Z",
      note: null,
      photos: null,
      categories: null,
      urls: null,
    },
    rawId: null,
  };
```

Right now I get all the contact with all the phones buy I need to display each contact with each phone number as I mentioned above.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please add your phoneNumbers object? This looks like a design level issue. If you have something like person id in phoneNumbers, then you can right a filter.

Comment: @Koga i added the template of the array of object , do you have any idea how to exact the value to display the same contact with different phone number if the person has multiple phone numbers? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using inner for loop which is iterating through phoneNumbers for each contact.

```
<ion-list lines="none" *ngFor="let c of myContacts" class="ion-no-padding">
         <div *ngFor="let p of c.phoneNumbers"
          <ion-item class="ion-no-padding" (ionChange)="onCheckbox($event)">
            <h5>{{c.name.givenName}} {{c.name.familyName}}</h5>
         </ion-item>
          <p class="phone">
            {{p.value}} </p
</ion-list>
```

You can see a working example using angular from here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-prfpsb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: its working perfectly , really appreciate. Just 1 more question , how about the email , if the user has 1-2-3 email how can i display the email exactly the same , same contact name with different email in the same ui ? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can do it by yourself! Give it a try :)

Comment: not sure if I have to create another div to loop the email array and aftere to display it , I will try , thanks a lot for your time.